# Merging individual tables?

Tags: mysql, database, rdbms

I have 5 tables. `table1`, `table2`, `table3`, `table4` and `table5`.

All these tables are indexed the same way, which means, for example, for name `john75de`, `table1` contains personal details
`table2` contains his skill set, `table3` contains the professional experience, `table4` contains the qualifications, and `table5` contains additional qualifications.

These tables have been there from the beginning, but I think I need to merge all of the data into one table because these 5 tables are all referenced using the same index. There are 500k names and details in all these tables.

There are no other cross-relations between names or any data. So what do you think.  Do I need to merge it?  If yes, how can I do it?   Since all the data relating to one name will be in a single row, I hope this will be easier. Oh, yeah, names are unique.

Comment: Maybe show some more details about the table structure

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like a bad idea to merge these tables. A person can have multiple addresses, multiple skills, multiple previous jobs and multiple qualifications. To model this you need one to many relationships, which is best done using separate tables.

If "qualifications" and "additional qualifications" have the same structure I might be tempted to merge those two tables into a single table. To do that you can select all rows from the one table and insert them into the other, then delete the unneeded table. If you need to distinguish between the two types of qualification you can add a column for that. Here's some example SQL for copying data from one table to the other:

```
INSERT INTO qualifications (col1, col2, ... coln, is_additional)
SELECT col1, col2, ... coln, 1
FROM addtional_qualifications
```

Merging two tables can be tricky if you have an AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY column with the same values in both tables, and other tables refer to these values via foreign key constraints.

Comment: what about database I/O five table will search for one name called John75de so it may affect performance or not??

Comment: It's hard to give a specific answer to this without more specific details about your application, but here's a piece of general advice: if you follow the generally accepted best practices for database design and normalization you will not go too far wrong. There are exceptions where the best practices won't work, but unless you really know what you are doing I would recommend sticking to the standard techniques. Having five tables instead of one is unlikely to give significant performance issues.